# How to read a .sql file using sqlite3 in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have come across a few articles [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-execute-an-external-sql-file-using-sqlite3-in-python)
But I couldn't understand whats going on and it was throwing me an error
**cursor.executescript(sql_as_string)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SET": syntax error**

This is my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import  sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

cursor = connection.cursor()

sql_file = open("databases/hott.sql")
sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
cursor.executescript(sql_as_string)

for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM airports"):
    print(row)
```

The SQL file I used [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_y3u4czFOt_eQADK8_iTAG0hrJwbRS3/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Add your query here which is giving the error... given link containing a huge number of queries..

Comment: Share your code so we can help you in a more precise way

Comment: Since you execute some SQL text via `cursor.executescript` you should include the text of your script, because no one can guess the content of the file. Did you test your script in SQLite console?

Comment: Please include your .SQL script in body of post not as an external GDrive link that may be forbidden by company proxies or result in a dead link for future readers. If script is lengthy, per your error provide sample lines where `SET` is used.